# Matlab cftool - fit using percentage deviation as criteria

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a strong varying data which I am trying to fit using custom function in `cftool` in Matlab. The issue is that the fit is done default using sum of squared errors (SSE) as criteria to minimize the fit. This results in large errors in fit for small values, since their offset's contribution to SSE is low.

I would like to do the fit with sum of squared relative deviation (percentage error) as minimum criteria. Is there a way to achieve this?

Of course, I can do this in a script form by explicitly mentioning the minimizing function. However, my equation form is not a finalized one and therefore, it is difficult to play with, if it is hard-coded in the script. I find the interactive `cftool` way of creating fits easier.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, the contribution of a mesure to SSE does not depend on its value it only depend on the offset.

Comment: Yes, small values need to have small offset whereas large values can have proportionately slightly large offset (to have same percentage error). But the contribution of the offset of the small value will be negligible in the SSE. Therefore, small values end up having `large percentage` error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to introduce sum of squared percentage error as criteria in Matlab cftool as follows.

The sum of squared errors (SSE) is computed as

[image]

It can be observed that there is some freedom through the weights. If we take

[image]

then this results in sum of squared percentage error. `y_i` is the data to be fitted.

Update: As James pointed out, necessary care has to be taken for y_i=0

Comment: When the value of y is zero, this weight is difficult to calculate.

Comment: Yes that is an important exception to be considered.